# Doctrine 2: How to update field with number of children?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

If I have two entities: `Parent` and `Child`, how can I run a single query and update `Parent.number_of_children` with the number of the related children?

I could iterate over every parent, but it can be easily done with a single query in MySQL for example, the question is how to do it in Doctrine 2 (with DQL perhaps)?

Comment: How about using `@ORM\PrePersist()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until anyone offers a better solution, I will go with the native SQL:

```
$entityManager -> getConnection() -> query("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

I woudl use `PrePersist` and `PreUpdate` events:

```
class Parent
{
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function onPrePersistAndUpdate()
    {
        $this->numberOfChildren = count($this->getChildren());
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but what about if I have 10000 parents with 10000 children each? With the native MySQL query I could do this without extracting ANY data from the database...